# A simple string array Iteration in C# .NET doesn't work

Tags: c#, string

This is a simple code that should return true or false after comparing each element in a String array with a Session Variable. The thing is that even when the string array named 'plans' gets the right attributes, inside the foreach it keeps iterating only over the first element, so if the Session Variable matches other element different than the first one in the array it never returns true... You could say the problem is right there in the foreach cicle, but I cant see it... I've done this like a hundred times and I can't understand what am I doing wrong... Thank you

```
protected bool ValidatePlans()
{
    bool authorized = false;

    if (RequiredPlans.Length > 0)
    {
        string[] plans = RequiredPlans.Split(',');
        foreach (string plan in plans)
        {
            if (MySessionInfo.Plan == plan)
                authorized = true;
        }
    }
    return authorized;
}
```

Comment: Please try to rephrase this question. Read it to yourself. Maybe I'm daft, but I really don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I don't think your analysis of the problem is correct. Have you run this under a debugger and stepped through the code? Additionally, you should accept some answers to your questions.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the text that might be in `RequiredPlans`?

Comment: Can you include an example value for RequiredPlans?

Comment: Sure, RequiredPlans is a String like ="Blue, Green", the problem is that even when the array has plans[0]="Blue", plans[1]="Green" it always iterates over the 0 element (Blue), it never gets to read the second one.

Comment: I tried the debugger and I don't understand why when this even iterates the right number of times, it never gets the correct element.

Comment: If u want to return authorized as true as soon as u find a match in the array...then u should break after "authorized=true" in the if statement

Comment: Your provided code works on my machine. Have you tried examining the value of `plan` inside the loop? Keep in mind that if your string is exactly is you say, then the second element will be `" Green"` (note the space at the start). Are you sure that's not the problem?

Comment: Is the if statement in your code `if(plan = MySessionInfo.Plan)` and the foreach `(string plan in plan)`? HUGE stretch, but that could cause the observed behavior.... actually probably not but maybe it's something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your problem, but I wonder if you're using a string like:

```
"Blue, Green"
```

...and expecting this method to return `true` when `MySessionInfo.Plan` is `"Green"` (no space). **If this is the problem then it's just a simple matter of there being an extra space in your `Split` result.** This could be fixed by changing this:

```
if (MySessionInfo.Plan == plan)
```

...to this:

```
if (MySessionInfo.Plan == plan.Trim())
```

If that's not it, then maybe I've misunderstood your problem.

**Edit**: From [your comment to HABJAN's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608897/a-simple-string-array-iteration-in-c-net-doesnt-work/4608981#4608981), I have to ask: is the code you *posted* **exactly the same** as the *actual code you're using*? If so I have to scratch my head, as it is very unclear how the modification he suggested (though it's a good one, as it makes the method more efficient) could have fixed your problem.

Comment: Mmm... it might be, let me try out!

Comment: Ok! So here it is how it worked! I used the Habjan's modification and your idea about using Trim... That way, it finally worked... I don't understand either how it fixed the loop but it did... Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: Dan the difference was once the match was made the method returned.  Before that he was just setting 'authorized' boolean and even if there was a match in the middle, the last item would always return false I am sure.  So once a match is made HABJAN's answer just returned out of the method essentially fixing the loop.

Comment: @Ryan: I disagree. Returning once a match is found is certainly more *efficient*; but it shouldn't have changed the method's behavior. Look at the example code he posted. He was *only* ever setting the `authorized` variable to `true` within the loop, never to `false`. So a single match *should* have ensured a return value of `true`.

Comment: Tou are right I should have seen that.  It was always returning false because there was no match, it was probably only the trim that did it or maybe a bad dev state/debug state confused the issue. Or maybe watching the compare variable over and over instead of the list being iterated. The authorized boolean not being set, I figured it was either a Trim or lower/uppercase compare issue. In fact I might have trimmed the string and lowered it before even splitting it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using [Array.IndexOf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat.aspx) instead of doing all the work yourself:

```
protected bool ValidatePlans()
{
    return (RequiredPlans.Length > 0
        && Array.IndexOf(RequiredPlans.Split(','), MySessionInfo.Plan) >= 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine to me, but you could replace the whole thing with:

```
return RequiredPlans.Length > 0 && RequiredPlans.Split(',').Any(s => MySessionInfo.Plan == s);
```

Comment: +1, nice shortcut (which, incidentally, I didn't see in my initial answer).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to explicity set the length of the the string array "plans" before adding values via the string.split...

EDIT: No I was wrong...your method of populating the array should work fine. Ignore my answer

Comment: I cant set it explictly because it's dynamic. May be another solution? RequiredPlans samples:

Comment: met.lord, have you done a count on plans before entering the loop and debugged immediately inside the loop to make sure it really is staying on blue or if Blue is the only string in counts when entering the loop?

Comment: Yes, I used the debugger, it has all the elements but it stays in blue =/

Answer (score 0):

```
protected bool ValidatePlans()
{   
    if (RequiredPlans.Length > 0)
    {
        string[] plans = RequiredPlans.Split(',');
        foreach (string plan in plans)
        {
            if (MySessionInfo.Plan == plan)
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: habjan, does this actually fix the loop? If so, how? Otherwise it only looks like you removed the authorized bool, and didn't answer the question.

Comment: It's strange, it actually fixed the loop, I don't understand why but, then again, when Plan matches plan it never returns true... I tried what other guys suggested and used Equal, but using equal resulted in loop again... This is so weird =(

Answer (score 0):

A few possibilities:

A. Assuming MySessionInfo.Plan is not strongly typed as a string, try

if(MySessionInfo.Plan.Equals(plan))
{
   authorized = true;
   break;
}

B. After doing the .split, during compare make sure there are no trailing spaces. You could do a MySessionInfo.Plan.Equals(plan.Trim())

C. Not sure what "foreach it keeps iterating only over the first element," means. Are you sure the loop doesn't go through the other elements in the array?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

> Sure, RequiredPlans is a String like
>   ="Blue, Green"

If this is what your input is looking like, then I think the problem isn't that you are iterating over the first value multiple times, but that you aren't trimming the values.  So everything after the first has a leading space and the match fails.

Try

```
if (MySessionInfo.Plan == plan.Trim())
```

Comment: Yes, that was one of the wrong things about my code! Thank you!

Comment: Cool man, glad you got it straight.  This would also lead me to believe a bigger issue might be your not understanding all of the information the debugger makes available to you.  For instance, when stepping through that loop you can hover over the "plan" variable to see its current value, or add it to quickwatch, or view it in the locals pane.  (you may know all this already, but figured I'd throw it out there in case it helps)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure RequiredPlans truly has unique string items, i.e. make sure it isn't returning Blue, Blue, Blue.

Second like others mentioned make sure to .Trim() the compare and why not throw in a .ToLower() to make sure there isn't case sensitive issues.

If all that is in it should clearly work. If not create a temporary RequiredPlans string to be sure it works as an individual test.

```
protected bool ValidatePlans()
{   
    if (RequiredPlans.Length > 0)
    {
        string[] plans = RequiredPlans.Split(',');
        foreach (string plan in plans)
        {
            if (MySessionInfo.Plan.Trim().ToLower() == plan.Trim().ToLower())
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```